# I want to make a notification error if one of field is empty

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make the customer to fill some fields, here is my code:

```
<form name="formLogin" method="post" action="makeit.php">

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Fullname:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input1" class="std" size="65" type="text" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">email:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input2" class="std" size="65" value="" type="password" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Six-digit pin:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input3" class="std" size="10" value="" type="password" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

now if one of fields is not filled, i want to error will show "you did not fill the email filed" same goes to other fields.

Comment: You should probably write code to deal with that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can valid each field of your form and show errors according them. For Example

**PHP COde**

```
<?php 
$userError = '';
if(isset($_POST['input1']) && !empty($_POST['input1'])){

//First assign some variables to posted variables like 
$fullname = $_POST["input1"];
$email = = $_POST["input2"];
$password = = $_POST["input3"];

//CHECK FULLNAME IS EMPTY
if($fullname == "") {
echo "Please Enter your Name First";
 }else if($email == "") { //IF EMAIL IS EMPTY
$userError = "Please Enter Your Email"; 
exit();
}else if($password == "") { //IF PASSWORD IS EMPTY
$userError = "Enter your password"; 
exit();
}else { //IF ALL FORM IS FILLED

   //SOME OTHER CODE
 }
}
?>
```

Create a php error variable to show errors like this 
**HTML FORM**

```
<form name="formLogin" method="post" action="makeit.php">

   <!-- show errors -->
   <?php echo $userError;?>
    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Fullname:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input1" class="std" size="65" type="text" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">email:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input2" class="std" size="65" value="" type="password" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Six-digit pin:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input3" class="std" size="10" value="" type="password" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

That's all.

Comment: but i don't want it to continue, i want it to stop and not let them go to other filed unless the fill the first one.

Comment: for this use javascript

Comment: Or you can use the above code to valid empty inputs

Answer (score 0):

First one, before you send form you could valid it by JS - e.g. check [jquery valid](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).
If 'makeit.php' is same file where form is, then you could do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['field_name']) && !empty($_POST['field_name'])){
//some code here
} else {
//error msg
}
```

BTW - Check also [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), especially if you want to valid email.